# Why does my balls keep speeding up after bouncing off the wall? [Verlet Integration]

Tags: animation, javafx, simulation

I am trying out simulation with Verlet Integration, but after two or so collisions, the balls speed up. Need advice with how to implement this, and possibly explaining why this happens. Thanks!

BouncingPane.java - handles the behaviour of balls.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane; 



public class BouncingPane extends Pane{

private ArrayList<Ball> balls;

public BouncingPane() {
    super();
    balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    this.setPrefSize(300, 300);
}

public void addBall(Ball b) {
    balls.add(b);
}

public ArrayList<Ball> getBallsCollection() {
    return balls;
}

public void render() {
    this.getChildren().addAll(balls);
}

public void updatePos() {
    Iterator<Ball> it = this.getBallsCollection().listIterator();
    Ball b;
    double x_new, y_new;
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        b = it.next();

        x_new = b.getCenterX();
        x_new += b.getCenterX() - b.getPX();

        if(x_new - b.getRadius() < 0) {
            x_new  = b.getRadius();
            b.setPX(b.getRadius() - (b.getPX() - b.getCenterX()));
            x_new = b.getRadius();
        }
        else if(x_new + b.getRadius() >= getWidth()) {
            x_new = getWidth() - b.getRadius();
            b.setPX(getWidth() - b.getRadius() + (b.getCenterX() - b.getPX()));
            x_new = getWidth() - b.getRadius();
        }
        else {
            b.setPX(b.getCenterX());
            b.setCenterX(x_new);
        }


        y_new = b.getCenterY();
        y_new += b.getCenterY() - b.getPY();

        if(y_new - b.getRadius() < 0) {
            y_new  = b.getRadius();
            b.setPY(b.getRadius() - (b.getPY() - b.getCenterY()));
            y_new = b.getRadius();
        }
        else if(y_new + b.getRadius() >= getHeight()) {
            y_new = getHeight() - b.getRadius();
            b.setPY(getHeight() - b.getRadius() + (b.getCenterY() - b.getPY()));
            y_new = getHeight() - b.getRadius();
        }
        else {
            b.setPY(b.getCenterY());
            b.setCenterY(y_new);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ball.java - Just a Circle class that tracks previous position

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Ball extends Circle{
    private double prevX;
    private double prevY;

    public Ball(double x, double y, double rad, Color col) {
        super(x, y, rad, col);
        prevX = 0;
        prevY = 0;
    }

    public void setPX(double x) {prevX = x;}
    public void setPY(double y) {prevY = y;}

    public double getPX() {return prevX;}
    public double getPY() {return prevY;}
}
```

Main.java - Where the UI is initialised. Some imports were not used (I just copied from my previous codes)

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();

    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BouncingPane canvas = new BouncingPane();
        Pane main = new Pane(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(main, 300, 300);
        Ball ball = new Ball(100, 100, 5, Color.RED);
        Ball ball1 = new Ball(50, 50, 5, Color.YELLOW);


        canvas.addBall(ball);
        canvas.addBall(ball1);

        ball.setPX(99.0);
        ball.setPY(98.0);

        ball1.setPX(49.0);
        ball1.setPY(51.0);

        canvas.render();

        stage.setTitle("Moving Ball");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


        startAnimation(canvas);
    }

    public void startAnimation(final BouncingPane canvas) {
        final AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        long lastTime = 0;
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(lastTime > 0) {
                    canvas.updatePos();
                }
                lastTime = now;
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: instead of storing the previous position and calculating the new one based on it, I recommend storing the velocity of a ball. This makes the calculations a bit simpler: `x = x + v_x` and if you need to bounce the ball of a vertical wall, you simply do `v_x = -v_x`. If you do want to keep storing it as 2 positions, I recommend computing the velocity in the loop to simplify the code a bit. Also take a look at enhanced for loops: Instead of dealing with the iterator yourself you could simply do `for (Ball b : balls) { ... }`

Comment: Hi @fabian, using velocity is called Euler method. It has less numerical stability than using Verlet integration, i.e using a slightly higher time lapsed per frame may lead to a drastically different result. 

But I do appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: @fabian  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Numerical_stability